# Asp.Net Web Api & JSON.Net - Deserialize body into .Net generic objects

Tags: json, list, dictionary, asp.net-web-api

I want to deserialize the body into .net classes (dictionary and list).

(so my code is transparent for xml and json)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]IDictionary<string, object> body)
        {
        }
```

Currently I use a converter to handle nested dictionary deserialization.

```
class IDictionaryConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IDictionary<string, object>>
{
    public override IDictionary<string, object> Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // in addition to handling IDictionary<string, object>
        // we want to handle the deserialization of dict value
        // which is of type object
        return objectType == typeof(object) || base.CanConvert(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

        // if the next token is not an object
        // then fall back on standard deserializer (strings, numbers etc.)
        return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

But nested JLists are not converted to List.
Maybe I can create a IListConverter, but is there an better way to do this?

I want in my web api only one code. not: if json do that, if xml do that...

Comment: Info: The nested list will not be deserialized as list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves my problem:

```
class IDictionaryConverter : CustomCreationConverter<IDictionary<string, object>>
    {
        public override IDictionary<string, object> Create(Type objectType)
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            // in addition to handling IDictionary<string, object>
            // we want to handle the deserialization of dict value
            // which is of type object
            return objectType == typeof(object) || base.CanConvert(objectType);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
                return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
                return serializer.Deserialize<IList<object>>(reader);

            // if the next token is not an object
            // then fall back on standard deserializer (strings, numbers etc.)
            return serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```